# npm http-server with header X-Content-Type-Options

Tags: npm, httpserver, x-content-type-options

Used
`$ http-server --cors .`
to serve the following that tried to access https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/dist/vue.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>

<body>
   DEMO
</body>

<script src="https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

</html>
```

However it posted the following error:

```
The resource from “https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/dist/vue.js” was blocked
due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

[image]

How to fix it or make `npm` `http-server` have `header` `X-Content-Type-Options`?